# AngularJS: basic error-handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, error-handling

I would like to reflect post request status by showing/hiding success/error html element with the error description. I have following controller with use of `$http` service:

```
$ctrl.addCorporateTransport = function() {
    var postStatusBar = angular.element('postStatusBar');
    $http.post('/post_corporate_transport', $ctrl.corporateTransport)
        .success(function () {
            // throw success alert 
        })
        .error(function (error) {
                // throw error alert 
        });
};
```

I'm looking for having possibility to throw `<div class="alert"><p>my error here</p>` if I hit error callback.

I tried this:

```
var statusBar = angular.element('postStatusBar');
//...
.success(function () {
     statusBar.setClass("alert-success")
})
.error(function (error) {
     statusBar.setClass("alert-danger");
     statusBar.setParameter("text", error);
});
```

But it doesn't work obviously and looks like anti-pattern. What is the best solution for doing the thing?

Comment: why dont you go for ng-show by setting some scope variables in responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the alert component is outside controller scope than you need make the alert a directive and use broadcast to notify and update properties like visibility.

else you can bind properties from controller like:

```
 <div ng-controller="AwesomeController as AwesomeCtrl">
          <div class="alert" ng-show="AwesomeCtrl.show.error">....
          <div class="alert" ng-show="AwesomeCtrl.show.success">....
          <div class="alert" ng-class="{ 'succes' : AwesomeCtrl.show.success }">....
```

enter code here

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AwesomeController', controller);

controller.$inject = ['$http'];

function controller($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.corporateTransport = {};
    vm.show = {
        error = false;
        success = false;
    }

    vm.oneCoolMethod = addCorporateTransport;

    // test
    addCorporateTransport();


    function addCorporateTransport() {
        $http.post('/post_corporate_transport', vm.corporateTransport)
            .success(onTransportSuccess)
            .error(onTransportError);
    };

    function onTransportSuccess(result) {
        toggleAlert('success');

    }

    function onTransportError(result) {
        toggleAlert('error');

    }

    function toggleAlert(level) {
        angular.forEach(vm.show, function(value, key) {
            vm.show[key] = false;
        });
        vm.show[level] = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

at the first you must using $scope.statusBar
and also addClass except setClass